# Add new Column to Android SQLite Database Create new table

Tags: android, sql

I want to add columns to table, i search before topics.
Seem they like to alert table. But i perfer to create new table.
So I try to do like this
`

```
@Override
public void onUpgrade(SQLiteDatabase db, int oldVersion, int newVersion) 
{

   db.execSQL("create table tmp_talbe name VARCHAR(50),number integer,number2 integer");

   db.execSQL("insert into tmp_table select * from origin_table");

   db.execSQL("drop if exists table origin_table");

   db.execSQL("alter tmp_talbe rename to origin_talbe");

}`
```

I have problem in copy old table data to new table.If i have 2 columns in old table, 3 colums in new table,
.It will show error 3 columns in tmp_table, but only 2 supplier.
Seem  code line 2 can't do like this,how to modify is better?

Comment: what is old table structure? and what are new column name?

Comment: I assume the old table name is "origin_talbe",structure is{NAME VARCHAR(50),NUMBER INTEGER}, new table name is "tmp_talbe" i add one column named number2 like {NAME VARCHAR(50),NUMBER INTEGER,NUMBER2 INTEGER}

Comment: [ALTER TABLE syntax](http://www.w3schools.com/sql/sql_alter.asp)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You got the error because 'select * from origin_table' only return 2 columns, NOT 3 columns and tmp_table has 3 columns.

I assume that the original table columns: **NAME, Number1** and You want to add **Number2** as third column:

Change

```
db.execSQL("insert into tmp_table select * from origin_table");
```

To

```
db.execSQL("insert into tmp_table select NAME, Number1, NULL as Number2 from origin_table");
```

Use NULL for third column when you copy data from Original table to Temp table.

You can also use any Default data for Third column.

Comment: I have a question. Because the db version may be differnet, the columns is different.If number of columns of the origin table is unknow,can i select all columns  like using * notation to new tables?

Comment: I think NO because 'SELECT INTO ... SELECT ... ' requires number of columns matches and orders of columns matches too. In your case. Depends on old_version and new_version. You can determine structure of old_version and new_version then you can make query properly.

Comment: Ok I understand, I always think if have a easy method can select all columns.Thank you Loc Ha , and sorry my poor English.

Comment: It seems you are new to here. Don't forget to accept the answer if you think it is right. It helps others.